# multiple row update with one SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I have two tables below

t1

```
-------------------------------------
| id | MaleCnt | FemaleCnt | flag |
------------------------------------
  1       20       null        1
  2       30       null        1
  3       40       null        1
```

t2

```
----------------------------
| id | FemaleCnt | flag |
----------------------------
  1       20        1
  2       30        1
  3       40        1
```

I want to update "FemaleCnt" at table t1 with table t2
(shoud have same id and flag)

---

I just wrote some query but dont work, so far.

Could you give me some tip??

Comment: Sample table data is great, but specify the expected result as well!

Comment: I hope you are doing this so you can drop table `t2` from your schema. It is a very bad idea keeping the same information in 2 places on a database

Comment: t2 is not a schema. t2 is made by internal query and I dont know how put the value of "femaleCnt" to t1

Comment: expected result is "updating all of t1 value(FemaleCnt) with t2 value(FemaleCnt)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `JOIN` & update :

```
UPDATE t1 INNER JOIN
    t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.flag = t1.flag
    SET t1.FemaleCnt = t2.FemaleCnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.FemaleCnt = t2.FemaleCnt 
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.flag = t2.flag
```